# Showing that limit of (f(x)) = L* lim(g(x))

Tags: limits

Suppose we are given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$ (finite), and also that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (g(x)) = 0$. Is it then necessarily true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)) = L \cdot \lim(g(x))$?

What I considered was we know the quotient rule of limits will not be applicable here that limit being limit of numerator and limit of denominator.

But still if we say limit of the denominator is close to zero, but not equal to zero, then we can shift that to other side by multiplying with that "close to zero" quantity on both sides?

Comment: To have a finite limite we need that $f(x)\to 0$ (necessary but not sufficient condition).

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {f(x)} {g(x)} g(x)$.

Comment: Hmm understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both limits exist, we can use the limit product rule and make the following computation:

$$L\cdot \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot g(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x).$$

But note also that since $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, all this really says is that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$. And this makes sense, doesn't it? If this would not be the case, then the first limit would not exist. For example, if we would have that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\alpha$ for some $\alpha\neq 0$, then $\lvert f\rvert $ would be bounded below by a positive constant in a neighborhood of $0$, but $\frac{1}{\lvert g(x)\rvert}$ would grow arbitrarily big as $x\to a$, meaning the limit couldn't possibly be finite. So even on an intuitive level we can see why this must be the case.

Comment: Nice i knew it intuitevely but i was trying to get it using quotient rule only . Forgot that multiplicatiom rule existed .

Comment: Could you have also used the quotient rule here?

Comment: Can you mention what quotient rule tells for limits for the zero denominator case once @lorago?  I mean its not true right that limit will be limit of N and Limit of D for that case ? Anything else it tells or somehow it can be used here ?

Comment: The quotient rule assumes that the limit of the denominator is nonzero, so it's not really applicable (and indeed that should be somewhat obvious, as we cannot divide by zero).